# Accessing and recovering files in C:\found.001\disk0001.chk

Tags: windows-7, chkdsk, file-recovery

Files disappeared from my computer. On running a system search, they were found in `C:\found.001\disk0001.chk`

I want to go in there and have a look, if there are other files there too, but it gives me an access denied message. I ran chkdsk but it said no problems.

Ideally I would want to run a recovery utility (not the ones for deleted files) that would restore them all to the respective locations. Though I am lucky, I still have them at this weird place.

I am on windows 7.

Comment: Does your user account have Administrator privileges on the computer?

Comment: The files were put there by chkdsk.  They are "lost" files (or parts of files) that were found to not be in any directory when chkdsk ran.  For security reasons they are probably only accessible to the administrator.  You should be able to sign on as administrator and move/rename them.

Comment: I am the administrator. And they are lost files. I can access them through the cmd all right. But I wanna get them all - each and everything and from gui. So I can 'see' what's there.

Comment: I don't know why the admin account wasn't being allowed to browse to that folder. But I made the System Files visible and copied all the found* folders, and then happily explored them. I think I can even delete the actual ones, since I have their copy with. Is it safe to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to recover them.
Search on google for

- UnCHK http://www.ericphelps.com/uncheck/
- Avira UnErase http://free-av.com/antivirclassic/avira_unerase.html

They are probably the best solution for you.

With these applications, it scans those CHK files and retrieves your files, without breaking the original chk examined one. it's been surely been made after a scandisk of some sort by windows, and it maybe found it corrupted, that's why it finished there.

Comment: Can you perhaps explain how these can help?  Real links would be nice as well. :)

Comment: Added links and in simple: They check your hard disk for the files and if still in good conditions, the software is able to give it back to you ;)

Comment: I would have used the unchk program to find out about my data or Avira UE to recover it, but, perhaps because of frequent defragging, there were very few files and all where in their wholesome state! with the extensions and filenames. So I just copied them :)

Thanks a lot for telling me about these.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, suddenly ALL files from My Pictures disappeared. Notably I was very upset since there were many precious pictures and videos. Sure, I had back-ups but they were unfortunately not up to date.

**My situation:**

- Lost pictures
- Tried Recuva to retrieve them
- Found out some of them were hidden in `C:\found.001\dir0000.chk\Korea`
- Ran chkdsk but showed no problems
- Tried to open `found.001` but it wouldn't show up in `C:\` nor could I go to it manually
- Tried to open `dir0000.chk` manually but couldn't
- Changing permissions did not allow me access nor would the folders show up in `C:\`
- I *could* go directly to `C:\found.001\dir0000.chk\Korea` but those were only the files from that submap of My Pictures

**Here's how I managed to retrieve the files**

- Used command prompt (run as administrator) to navigate to the files
- Copied them to an external USB using command prompt

That's all there was to it. I hope anyone who finds this post is able to retrieve some of their precious files this way. Below you can find some of the command I used in navigating command prompt

- `cd C:\` (navigates you to C:)
- `dir` (Shows all files in the directory
- `copy C:\hello.txt F:\`  (Copies hello.txt to F:)
- `xcopy /s /i F:\Folder1\ E:\`  (Copies F:\Folder1 and all subfolders and files to E:)

Good luck!