# How to recover corrupted then replaced drive c

Tags: windows, hard-drive

Here's what happened to me since last night:

1- I was normally using my PC when suddenly the blue screen of death appeared (CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED): http://www.reviversoft.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/critical_process_died_windows_8.png

2- I restarted my PC, the windows didn't start, it used to freeze with a blank blue screen after the bios start.

3- I inserted the windows 8 CD, then went to the installation process, but didn't install, went to Explorer instead, and tried to explore drive c:, it didn't work, a pop-up showed up: "The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable".

4- I went to cmd and made 'chksk', after it finished, I was able to explore my c: drive, but all my files and folders were gone. It looked like over 95% of the contents those were in drive c: has gone.

5- I installed a new windows, but still contents are deleted.

6- I noticed that the used space of drive c: is 50 GB, but when I open it and select all files (including system and hidden), then click properties, the used space is 50 GB only, which means there's 20 GB (most likely the deleted files exist somewhere).

7- I tried many partition/files recovery software, but no luck.

Any one knows what to do to recover my old c: drive?

UPDATE:

It looked like the chkdsk is what caused this problem, the system created 3 folders named (found.000,found.001,found.002), and the files inside them are named (dir0000.chk... etc).

These folders have space over 10 GB.

UPDATE 2:

Some of the old files still exists, but in a form of chkdsk folders: (found.000,found.001,found.002... etc), and (dir_000004C1.chk, dir_000004C2.chk... etc).

Probably I didn't complete the chkdsk process or I made it wrong.

How can I 'unpack' or recover from these chkdsk folders as they were before the corruption?

Comment: You already overwrote the data when you installed windows on the drive.  It is to late to recover the data

Comment: Replace the drive. Reinstall Windows. Restore your data from backup. You do have a backup, right? Also, chkdsk didn't `create` the problem.

Comment: I made update 2, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a failing drive. Replace it and restore from backup.

Any files recovered by CHKDSK are already recovered, you just have to pick through them to identify them and keep what you need.  Since they are already recovered, recovery software can't really do anything further.

If you have no backup, then judging by your statement of "I tried many partition/files recovery software, but no luck.", your choices are to either send it off to a professional data recovery company and pay them to recover it (if they can, they will diagnose first for free usually), and/or just give up, start over, and take it as a lesson learned -- KEEP BACKUPS.

Regarding your 2nd update:

The "Found" and ".CHK" files *are* what CHKDSK recovers. It doesn't recover the file names or the folder structure, as the corruption disjointed the data (the actual files) from the index table (where the names, and folder relationships are stored).

For more information on what you can do with those folders/files, check out this other SU question: [Accessing and recovering files in C:\found.001\disk0001.chk](https://superuser.com/questions/410062/accessing-and-recovering-files-in-c-found-001-disk0001-chk)

Comment: I made update 2, please check.

Comment: @AhmedSaad Updated my answer to respond to your 2nd update. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you own a USB-to-SATA adapter? you can retrieve most of the time the data from the HDD by connecting it to a working computer and it shows as additional hard drive under Computer/My Computer (depending on the system version).

As already stated, a good way to avoid future headache is to have a backup (full or partial) somewhere else.

I would highly suggest having a backup either by DVD or External HDD (2+ TB would be ideal); recently you can use Dropbox, Box or Google Drive.

Another suggestion is by having a second HDD on the PC and have your files on that drive. If the C drive fails you can still access your files.

Hope this helps.

Brice,
ITSS

Comment: I made update 2, please check.