# External HDD shows only dir.XXXXX files

Tags: external-hard-drive

Hello i have an external HDD witch shows that the hdd is full and when i'm going on the hdd i have just 1 million of dir0000, dir0001 files and i would like to know if is possible to recover something from this hdd.

thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing and recovering files in C:\found.001\disk0001.chk](https://superuser.com/questions/410062/accessing-and-recovering-files-in-c-found-001-disk0001-chk)[.](https://superuser.com/questions/820435/how-to-recover-corrupted-then-replaced-drive-c)